# Simplified query to get sum of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I use the following SQL to get the logistics costs from the database:

```
SELECT country, sum(Costs_Inbound), sum(Costs_Storage), sum(Costs_Outbound),
       (sum(Costs_Inbound) + sum(Costs_Storage) + sum(Costs_Outbound)) as Total
FROM Logistics
GROUP BY country WITH ROLLUP;
```

The `SQL Fiddle` with the database can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e95b3/1). 
All this works fine so far.

---

Now I was wondering if it possible to simplify the second sum statement by referring to the column expressions in the first row because - as you can see - right now I copy each column expression from the first row into the second row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify it with single `SUM()`:

```
SELECT country, SUM(Costs_Inbound), SUM(Costs_Storage), SUM(Costs_Outbound),
       SUM(Costs_Inbound + Costs_Storage + Costs_Outbound) as Total
FROM Logistics
GROUP BY country WITH ROLLUP;
```